# having a variable in recursive method not redefine itself after each call

Tags: java, recursion

I am going to post my code below because this is kind of hard to describe. The code below works, but it is using Math.pow in the main method rather than in the helper, so if someone could show me a way to move the power to the helper method without messing up the program that would be much appreciated.

Main method:

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
  double input = keyboard.nextInt();

  double x = Math.pow(2.0, input);
  int n = (int)x;

  System.out.println(starStr(n));
```

Helper method:

```
  public static String starStr(int n)
  {     
     if (n >= 1) {
        return ("*" + starStr(n-1));
     }
     else {
        return "";
     }
  }
```

EDIT:

```
 if(n == 0) {
     return "*";
  }   
  else {
     return starStr(n - 1) + "**";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. You don't really need to use a power function at all. Just start with 1 star and double the number of stars in every step of the recursion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the number of stars: ");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println(doStars(input));
}

public static String doStars(int n)
{
    //If n == 0 the recursion is done
    //Otherwise, reduce n by 1 and double the number of stars
    if(n == 0)
        return "*";
    else
    {
        String output = doStars(n - 1);
        return output + output;
    }
}
```

Comment: @golden_kiwi I've updated the code to require only one input. See if that's more what you're looking for.

Comment: So I just changed the return statement to return doStars(n-1) + "*"; and changed the if n==0 return to an empty string "" and it works. Not sure exactly why though, if anyone understands why could you explain it? Just for my own knowledge, otherwise I think I got it working.

Comment: @golden_kiwi - My answer has a little bit of explanation.

Comment: @golden_kiwi Are you still calling Math.Pow() on the user input in the beginning? You don't need to do that anymore, the recursive nature of the function takes care of it by itself. That would explain your problems though.

Comment: @NathanHughes Yeah, thought of that just after I edited it. I'll change it again.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that I had forgotten to take that out. Let me give it a go right now and see if its working.

Comment: That seems to be working perfectly. Thank you so much @Jeffersah. Just out of curiosity, what is the logic behind this working? From what I understand, it is recursing through until n = 0 and making output a string of stars of length n, then printing this twice? By that logic inputting 3 should give 6 stars, so clearly I am missing something. Otherwise it works perfectly though, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Not sure if you have learned the tree data-structure, but that's the purpose of my variable names.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // 1 + (2^n)-1 = 2^n 
            System.out.println("*" + doStars(i));
        }
    }

    public static String doStars(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            String subTree = doStars(n - 1); 
            return subTree + "*" + subTree; // length = (2^n)-1
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
*
**
****
********
****************
```

**Visualization** - read clockwise in triangles from little to big

```
                        "*"
                         +
                     doStars(2)
                        "*"
      doStars(1)         +        doStars(1)
          "*"                         "*"
doStars(0) + doStars(0)     doStars(0) + doStars(0)
   ""           ""              ""          ""
```

Comment: I believe this answer is also correct, you just moved the last star from case 0 to in between the two returns. Haven't learned the tree structure though so the explanation has me a little lost. Thank you so much though.

Comment: It's a fun one once you understand it. Really helped me understand recursive programming. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order

Comment: Thank you man, recursion is the first thing so far that has given me trouble. Definitely going to put some time into this.

Comment: For my visualization, you read it bottom-up 2-3 lines at a time in chunks of 3's (triangles). So in the bottom left, `doStars(0)` returns `""`, which is why it is above it. Move up a line and you add those together with `"*"`. Do the same in the bottom right. Move up to `doStars(2)` and you add the left 'tree' with the right 'tree' and another `"*"` in between. Then, at the top, add another `"*"`.